# How to list and determine the size(in Bytes/KBs) of each item stored in Application Cache

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Need to list Items in the application cache of a asp.net web forms application and the size(in Bytes/KB) of each item.

To List the Item Keys I used following code

```
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    chacheList.Add(new CacheDetails()
    {
        CacheKey = (string) enumerator.Key
    });
}
```

When using the following approach an error occurs for few items. The Exception message - " is not marked as serializable. "

```
foreach (var item in chacheList)
{
    var cacheObject = Cache.Get(item.CacheKey);

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] Array;
    bf.Serialize(ms, cacheObject);
    Array = ms.ToArray();
    var memsize = Array.Length;
    ..
    ..
}
```

How to overcome the above problem?

Comment: I guess that the error occurs in `bf.Serialize(ms, cacheObject)`. Assumed `item` is `WebDictionary` & `chacheList` is a collection of `WebDictionary`, then `cacheObject` returns `object` from `Cache.Get()` and object source (`chacheList`) possibly require either implementing `ISerializable` or marked with `SerializableAttribute`.

Comment: Application cache contains objects created from non serializeable classes.
Is there any way to get the size of an Obeject created from non-serializable class?